# Will a Master in Science (Statistics) helps in landing a job

Tags: masters, job-search, job, statistics

I specialize in Pure Maths when I was a undergraduate. Currently I am working in a university as a teaching assistant.

I would like to find an industrial job. However, due to my lack of applied maths knowledge, I couldn't find any. So I thought of taking a Master in Science, particularly Statistics, so that I have real-life application mathematics background to assist me in finding a job.

Question: Will this actually work out? Will employer trust my knowledge obtained from my Master degree? To what extent?

Answer (score 1):

We can't answer if it will work out but...

Almost everyone who goes to get a degree does so to help their career. You'll be there for the same reason as your peers and most people who have ever gone to college.